# Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp, apache-poi

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Excel Web View</title>

  <%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
  <%@ page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter" %>
  <%@ page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*" %>
  <%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*"%>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">

  <%

    String filename="C:"+ File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "Yatin Relhan" + File.separator +"Downloads" + File.separator + "CSV_Database_of_First_Names.xls";
    String extension = "";

    int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i >= 0) {
      extension = filename.substring(i+1);
    }

    if(extension !=null && extension.contains("xlsx"))
    {

      if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
        try{

          FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
          XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fs);
          for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
            int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

            for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
              XSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);

              int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
  %>

  <tr>

    <%
    for(int n=0;n<cells;n++)
    {
  %>


    <td>
  <%
    formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(n));
  %>
    </td>
    <%
  }
%></tr><%
        }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
else {
  if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
    try{
      FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
      HSSFWorkbook  wb = new HSSFWorkbook (fs);
      for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
        int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
          HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
          int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
%>

  <tr>

  <%
  for(int n=0;n<cells;n++){
%>
    <td>

  <%
  formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(n));
%>
</td>

  <%
  }
%>
  </tr>
  <%
          }
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to following JSP file which I'm trying to run on Tomcat server. I have imported the necessary JARs but I get the following errors

```
An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [C:\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Hi\org\apache\jsp\NewFile_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [33] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
30:         try{
31: 
32:             FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
33:             XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fs);
34:             for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
35:             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
36:             int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();


An error occurred at line: [33] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
30:         try{
31: 
32:             FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
33:             XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fs);
34:             for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
35:             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
36:             int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();


An error occurred at line: [35] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
XSSFSheet cannot be resolved to a type
32:             FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
33:             XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fs);
34:             for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
35:             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
36:             int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
37:             DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
38: 


An error occurred at line: [37] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
34:             for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
35:             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
36:             int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
37:             DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
38: 
39:             for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
40:             XSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);


An error occurred at line: [37] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
34:             for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
35:             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
36:             int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
37:             DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
38: 
39:             for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
40:             XSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);


An error occurred at line: [40] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
XSSFRow cannot be resolved to a type
37:             DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
38: 
39:             for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
40:             XSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
41: 
42:             int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); 
43:             %><tr>


An error occurred at line: [65] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
62:            if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
63:            try{
64:                 FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
65:                 HSSFWorkbook  wb = new HSSFWorkbook (fs);
66:                 for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
67:                 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
68:                 int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();


An error occurred at line: [65] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
62:            if(filename != null && !filename.equals("")){
63:            try{
64:                 FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
65:                 HSSFWorkbook  wb = new HSSFWorkbook (fs);
66:                 for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
67:                 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
68:                 int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();


An error occurred at line: [67] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
HSSFSheet cannot be resolved to a type
64:                 FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream(filename);
65:                 HSSFWorkbook  wb = new HSSFWorkbook (fs);
66:                 for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
67:                 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
68:                 int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
69:                 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
70: 


An error occurred at line: [69] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
66:                 for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
67:                 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
68:                 int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
69:                 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
70: 
71:                 for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
72:                     HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);


An error occurred at line: [69] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
66:                 for(int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++){
67:                 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
68:                 int rows  = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
69:                 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
70: 
71:                 for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
72:                     HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);


An error occurred at line: [72] in the jsp file: [/NewFile.jsp]
HSSFRow cannot be resolved to a type
69:                 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
70: 
71:                 for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
72:                     HSSFRow row   = sheet.getRow(r);
73:                     int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); 
74:                 %><tr><%
75:                     for(int n=0;n<cells;n++){
```

Also the stack trace is as follows.

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:601)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I write a java program for the same and add the same JARs to my project structure it runs fine. What could be the problem?

I tried searching on the net. One solution was to restart the server, that did not work. Another was to check if the JARs were included, done that.

Comment: The message indicates that the class could not be found on the classpath of your deployed application. Did you make sure that the POI jar is in your WEB-INF/lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
mybe you can try to open %TOMCAT_HOME%conf\server.xml and add context
for example: 
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Context path="access address" docBase="your project path" reloadable="true">
    </Context>
   </Host>
```